# Javascript Div reload

Tags: javascript, php, html

My code contains 6 divs with an id: autoRefresh each have different queries. I need to refresh them every minute using a script. Mine works but displays the entire page inside the divs. The divs and script are in the same mainMenu.php

```
<div id="autoRefresh">  
        <?php
        //Query and process are here working as a charm
        ?>
<div id="autoRefresh">
<div id="autoRefresh">
<div id="autoRefresh">
<div id="autoRefresh">
<div id="autoRefresh">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
setInterval(function () {
$('#autoRefresh').load('mainMenu.php');
}, 10000);
```

});

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: You cannot have multiple divs with same id. You should use class instead of id.

Comment: You would benefit if you were to re-word this as a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because each div have different content/query, i think you need 6 divs with unique ids, and 6 PHP script that upload them with the right content.

```
<div id="div_1"></div>
<div id="div_2"></div>
<div id="div_3"></div>
<div id="div_4"></div>
<div id="div_4"></div>
<div id="div_5"></div>
<div id="div_6"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
      $('#div_1').load('query_1.php');
      $('#div_2').load('query_2.php');
      $('#div_3').load('query_3.php');
      $('#div_4').load('query_4.php');
      $('#div_5').load('query_5.php');
      $('#div_6').load('query_6.php');
    }, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `id` you could use the `class` attribute for the div.
class dont have to be unique.You could change it to `<div class="autoRefresh">`
and use `$('.autoRefresh')` the load method will load all html data sent from the server http://api.jquery.com/load/

what does the php file you load return? add the code belonging to that file..

Comment: The scripts and divs are in the same php. The divs displays numbers in the web page.